# CSS градиентная анимация фона

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, css-animation

Я хочу создать анимацию пробега сияния, которая будет применяться на нескольких элементах с разными цветами фона.

В настоящее время я использую градиент `background-image` и анимирую `background-position` с помощью блоков `vw`. Но это не масштабируется, мои элементы будут иметь разную длину.

Есть ли способ, при котором я смогу анимировать `background-image` с процентными единицами?

Созданная анимация:

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    to right,
    transparent 0%,
    rgba(255,255,255,0.3) 50%,
    transparent 100%
  );
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: -100vw;
  animation: shine 2s infinite;
}

@keyframes shine {
  0% {
    background-position: -100vw;    
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 100vw;   
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>  
</head>
<body>
  
  <header></header>
  

</body>
</html>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Responsive shine animation using linear-gradient as background](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55989735/7394871) от участника  [@Sartre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11454468/sartre).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/55989735/7394871

Answer (score 6):

Идея состоит в том, чтобы сделать размер градиента в 3 раза больше, чем контейнер, и закрасить его среднюю часть, а затем передвинуть его слева направо:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

.box {
  height: 50px;
  margin:5px;
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    to right,
    transparent 33%,
    rgba(255,255,255,0.3) 50%,
    transparent 66%
  );
  background-size:300% 100%;
  animation: shine 2s infinite;
}

.one {
background-color: rebeccapurple;
} 
.two {
background-color: #561499;
}

.three {
background-color: #351556;
}
@keyframes shine {
  0% {
    background-position: right;    
  }
  /*100% {
    background-position: left; it's the default value, no need to define it
  }*/
}
```

```html
<div class="box one" ></div>

<div class="box two" style="width:60%"></div>

<div class="box three" style="width:40%"></div>
```

### Update

Еще одна альтернатива другой анимации:

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

.box {
  height: 50px;
  margin:5px;
  background: 
    repeating-linear-gradient(90deg,#0000 0,rgba(255,255,255,0.3) 25%,#0000 50%)
    rebeccapurple;
  background-size:200% 100%;
  animation: shine 1s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes shine {
  0% {
    background-position: right;    
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>

<div class="box" style="width:60%"></div>

<div class="box" style="width:40%"></div>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55989998/7394871) от участника  [@Temani Afif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8620333/temani-afif).</sub>